# Proving Divergence of Sequence using epsilon-$N$ defintion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble proving that a sequence is divergent using the epsilon-$N$ definition of limits. The limit I am trying to prove is divergent is $\frac{n^3-15n-3}{n^2}$.

So, I started by assuming that it converges to some $L$ and I set $\epsilon=1$. Then I plugged the sequence and $L$ into $|\frac{n^3-15n-3}{n^2}-L|<1$ and got that $L>n-1$. I reached this point. I'm stuck here. Can someone please help me?

Comment: This is how you convergences, this sequence diverges.. recheck your definitions.

Comment: You want to show that for any $M$, exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, the sequence $a_n > M$

Comment: its pretty easy - just chose for every (M >= 0) N = 100M^M for an extreme example

Answer (score 1):

Try this: note that $\frac{15n+3}{n^2}$ is less than $\frac{16}{n}\leq 1$ for $n\geq 16$. Therefore, for $n\geq 16$, $$\frac{n^3-15n-3}{n^2}\geq n-\frac{16}{n}\geq n-1$$ Therefore, for any $M$, let $N = \max(16, \lceil M\rceil+1)$, and you will have that $$\frac{n^3-15n-3}{n^2}\geq n-1\geq N-1\geq \lceil M\rceil\geq M$$ for all $n\geq N$, so the sequence diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: How does the last part show that the sequence diverges?

Comment: Also, what is M, what definition are you using?

Comment: A sequence $\{x_n\}$ diverges to $\infty$ iff for every $M > 0$, there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $x_n\geq M$. This is the definition of divergence to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$|\frac{n^3-15n-3}{n^2}| > |\frac{n^3-15n-4}{n^2}| = |\frac{(n-4)(n^2+4n+1)}{n^2}| > |\frac{(n-4)(n^2+4n+1)}{n^2+4n+1}| = |n-4|$ Then, $\forall n>4$ we have to diverge

Comment: Why for n>4 we have it diverge?

Comment: If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ has a boundary then it converges and $a_n $ converges to that boundary. On the other hand, if the sequence is not convergent then it is divergent.

Comment: I still don't see how you went from $...=|n-4|$ Then, ... diverge. Can you add some reasoning why it diverges?

Comment: For each 'n' you take, its sequence is increasing, it is like it has no upper limit, another definition is $lim sup (a_n) = lim inf (a_n)$, then $(a_n)$ is convergent. But in this case its $'(a_n)'$ has no upper limit, ie, it has no sup.

Comment: -3> -4, then the first inequality ok ?, I adjusted so that we would have at least one root on top, hence achieving this equality. and note that $n^2 <n^2 + 4n + 1$, since $n \in \mathbb {N}$, then $\frac {1} {n ^ 2}> \frac {1} {n ^ 2 + 4n +1}$. So

Comment: the new sequence acts as follows:$ (bn) = (n-4)$
$(1,2,3,4,5,6, ...) \forall n> 4$, so for every n you take is only growing. And by the criterion of comparison if I have its sequences (an) and (bn) such that an> bn, if bn diverges an also diverges, now converge to bn convergence...

Comment: Did you get the rationale?

Comment: if take, $n>A+4$, then $|n-4|>A, \forall n>4$. we have to diverge